# How can I reset the timer again using clearInterval()?

Tags: javascript, html, timer, setinterval, clearinterval

I have looked at the other threads about this question, but so far I have found no solution that fits my problem. I want to create a timer that activates using an addEventListener, in which I will use a setInterval(). Then I want to have a "pause" button that can pause the setInterval(), which I did by using clearInterval().

My problem is that, once I pause my timer once, I cannot get the timer to continue counting again by clicking the same button that starts the timer in the first place. This is my code:

```
hour=document.getElementById("hour"); 
minute=document.getElementById("minute");
second=document.getElementById("second");
start=document.getElementById("start")
reset=document.getElementById("reset") 
pause=document.getElementById("pause");
var countdown;
start.addEventListener("click", function clicked() { 
    countdown = setInterval(function() { 
        if (second.textContent!="59") {
            let new_second=Number(second.textContent)+1;
            second.textContent=new_second; 
    }
        else { 
            second.textContent="00"; 
            if (minute.textContent!="59") { 
                let new_minute=Number(minute.textContent)+1;
                minute.textContent=new_minute;
        }
            else { 
                minute.textContent="00";
                let new_hour=Number(hour.textContent)+1; 
                hour.textContent=new_hour;
            }
        }
    }, 1000)
    this.outerHTML=this.outerHTML;
}, false);
pause.addEventListener("click", function() { 
    clearInterval(countdown);
})
reset.addEventListener("click",function() { 
    clearInterval(countdown);;
    second.textContent="00"; 
    minute.textContent="00"; 
    hour.text.Content="00";
})
```

Thank you all for your help!

Comment: if you click twice the first interval gets overwritten and you get two intervals running at once, you need to check if you've already created one

Comment: I think I figured out what the problem is. The line "this.outerHTML=this.outerHTML;" causes the start button's event to be deleted after the first click. If I delete this line, then the pause button works just fine. However, another problem occurs, which is that if users click on "start" multiple times, then the setInterval() will be called repeatedly and hence, pollute the program. Does anyone have a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

outerHTML destroys the original start button (and creates a new instance), and thus the event listener you attached to it is no longer valid.  Fixed code here:

```js
hour=document.getElementById("hour"); 
minute=document.getElementById("minute");
second=document.getElementById("second");
start=document.getElementById("start")
reset=document.getElementById("reset") 
pause=document.getElementById("pause");
var countdown;
start.addEventListener("click", function clicked() { 
    // alternatively you can clearInterval here every time
    if(!countdown)
    countdown = setInterval(function() { 
        if (second.textContent!="59") {
            let new_second=Number(second.textContent)+1;
            second.textContent=new_second; 
    }
        else { 
            second.textContent="00"; 
            if (minute.textContent!="59") { 
                let new_minute=Number(minute.textContent)+1;
                minute.textContent=new_minute;
        }
            else { 
                minute.textContent="00";
                let new_hour=Number(hour.textContent)+1; 
                hour.textContent=new_hour;
            }
        }
    }, 1000)
}, false);
pause.addEventListener("click", function() { 
    clearInterval(countdown);
    countdown=null;
})
reset.addEventListener("click",function() { 
    clearInterval(countdown);
    countdown=null;
    second.textContent="00"; 
    minute.textContent="00"; 
    hour.textContent="00";
})
```

```html
<div id="hour"></div>
<div id="minute"></div>
<div id="second"></div>
<div id="start">start</div>
<div id="reset">reset</div>
<div id="pause">pause</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! However, another problem occurs, which is that if users click on "start" multiple times, then the setInterval() will be called repeatedly and hence, pollute the program. Does anyone have a solution to this problem?

Comment: you can clear it every time, or check its existence

Comment: Can you elaborate on how I can clear the setInterval() on the start button without stopping the timer? I want to clear it while keeping the clock counting. It seems to me that if I add a clearInterval(countdown) in the event of the button, it will just stop the timer altogether.

Comment: you stop the timer, and then just start another one.  you're starting a new one anyways so it doesn't matter.  that will cause a slight delay on pressing start.  it's simpler because you just clear it every time.  the other method is to check for countdown and then null it out when you clearInterval